# Does one have to stand when the Ark is open?

Tags: halacha, standing-sitting, ark-aron-kodesh

I heard only when the Torah is taken out, not when open. What is the actual Halacha and if you do need to stand, is there a leniency if ones legs hurt?

Answer (score 5):

It is a demonstration of honour to stand but not a duty. See [here](http://din.org.il/2014/12/01/%D7%94%D7%90%D7%9D-%D7%99%D7%A9-%D7%97%D7%99%D7%95%D7%91-%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%9B%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A9-%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%97/)

The original rule is this (SA YD 282, 2):

> הרואה ספר תורה שהוא מהלך חייב לעמוד לפניו ויהיו הכל עומדים עד שיעמוד זה שמוליכו ויגיענו למקומו או עד שיתכסה מעיניהם. ‏
>
> Everybody need to stand when they see a Sefer Torah walking until it reach his place (for instance the ark).

The link quote **SA YD 242, 18** and a comment of the Taz sk 13 which answered exactly the OP.

**SA:**

> אם קראו לרבו לקרות בתורה בצבור אינו צריך לעמוד כל זמן 
>   שרבו עומד: ‏
>
> If his Rabbi is called to read on Torah in congregation, he is doesn't everytime that his Rabbi stands.
>
> הגה: וכן כשהרב עומד למעלה בבית והתלמיד על הקרקע א"צ לעמוד לפניו **ואפי' כשהס"ת על הבימה אין צבור שבבהכ"נ צריכים לעמוד דהספר ברשות אחרת** (ב"י בשם תשובת הרשב"א): ‏
>
> The Rama quoted A responsum of the Rashba which is quoted in Bet Yosef: One priniple is explained concerning standing by respect. This is necessary only if you and the honorable object are in a same area. One of the given examples is, if the Sefer Torah is up the Bima (which is hight than 10 tefachim {and its surface is more than 4x4 tefachim, following the definition of reshut harabim in Shabbat}), its domain is the Bima and you are not up the bima vut stand over the ground. You need not to stand.

**The Taz in sk 13** wrote:

> וגם בזמן שספר תורה מונחת בארון הקודש אף על פי שהוא פתוח אלא שהעולם עושין כן דרך כבוד לעמוד כל שהארון הקודש פתוח ואין חיוב בדבר. ‏
>
> When the Sefer Torah is in the holy Ark,  even if the Ark is open, we have not to stans. But people stand by respect when the Ark is open, this is not a duty.

The second source cited in the link is: **Shaar Hatsiun OC 146, sk 18**:

> ובפרי מגדים כתב דאפילו הוא עומד עמה (כגון בעת שמזכיר החזן נשמות), גם כן אינו מחויב אז לקום לפניה כיון שהחזן עומד עמה במקום אחד.  לפי זה הוא הדין בעת שפותחים הארון כי הלא בכל זה במקומה מונחת. והעולם נוהגים בכל זאת לעשות הידור לתורה ולעמוד ועיין באליה רבה שדעתו דבעת הגבהה מחויבים הכל לעמוד אף שהיא ברשות אחרת. וטעמו דהרי הוא מגביה להראות לעם ומחוייבים בכבודה. ‏
>
> Pri Megadim allows to sit when the Chazan stand with the sefer Tora in  his hands. The mi hag is to stand. An Eliahu Rabba said that for hagbaha we must to stand because the Magbiah voluntary shows thr ST.

{May be that the fact that we voluntary open the ark for Neila has something to do with the svara of Eliah Rabba, so we can perhaps understand the rule cited by Sabbahillel}

Comment: I thought this was why we stand for Ne'ilah.  Are your sources saying that's just custom and not halacha?

Comment: As Art Scroll Machzor for Yom Kippur says, if one cannot stand during the entire chazaras hashatz of neilah (which has the ark open for the entire time), he may sit at those places when one would not have to stand if the ark was closed.

Comment: @Monica Cellio The Taz told about this custom and did not disagree with it, he just said that the cause is not a prohibition to sit.  I will improve. the post further

Comment: @sabbahillel see edit at end

Comment: I'm not seeing the relevance of the 2nd quote to answering the question.

Comment: @DanF you mean th shaar hatsiun?

Comment: The 2nd blockquote that deals with the rav being called for an aliyah.

Comment: @DanF in this sayif we see the principle of two places, if the public is in an other place he is patur from standing. 2nd step, the aron hakodeshvis also a separated place

Answer (score 2):

[HaRav Dor Lior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dov_Lior) [states](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/5036) (my translation):

> אומנם צריך לכבד את ארון הקודש אך מכיוון שמצד עיקר הדין מותר לשבת בזמן שארון הקודש פתוח, לכן, מי שקשה לו יכול לשבת.
>
> While one needs to honor the Aron Qodesh, since one is permitted to sit when the Aron Qodesh is open according to the letter of the law ('Iqar HaDin), one is permitted to sit if it is difficult for him [to stand].