# Simchas Torah Hakofos participation requirement

Tags: halacha, simchat-torah

Can someone sit during his Shul's hakofos or is there an actual obligation to walk around the bimah? Does one have to hold the sefer torah? Does one have to say the pesukim in the Siddur that introduce each hakafah?

Comment: I don't believe there's an obligation to do anything pertaining to hakafos. This might come as a shock to some, but Sinchas Torah is mentioned nowhere in either Tanach or Shas.

Comment: Whether one can sit during _hakafos_ is a separate question (because generally Jews stand when a Torah a scroll is being walked around), one that (I thought we had already but don't now find so) you may wish to split off into a separate question post.

Comment: No to all. Hakafot are neither a biblical nor a rabbinic requirement.they are just a recent custom.

Comment: @mevaqesh. Don't customs/minhagim also create obligations?

Comment: From my limited experience that is relatively recent idea. Earlier writers tended to use custom as a way of determining between competing halakhic opinions, not to create new obligations without halakhic justification out of thin air.

Comment: What is one obligated to do when the Torah is removed from the ark for reading on any day?

Comment: @MarkA. "Don't customs/minhagim also create obligations?" Only for certain definitions of those terms. Are you intending to play semantic games here? Because if you are then no one is interested in playing along.

Comment: My rav instructed a few congregants including me NOT to dance during hakafot during the year of mourning for a parent. The reason is that Simchat Torah hakafot is a rather "late" minhag (I think as late as 16h century) and a mourner is not allowed to dance and be joyous.

Comment: @DanF A mourner is allowed to and is in fact obligated to be joyous on Yom Tov.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Mishna Berura 669 sk 11:

> ...ולכן יש להתאמץ בזה לרקד ולזמר לכבוד התורה כמו שכתוב גבי דהע"ה מפזז ומכרכר בכל עוז לפני ד' וכ"כ משם האר"י ז"ל
>
> והעידו על האר"י ז"ל שאמר שהמעלה העליונה שהשיג באה לו ע"י שהיה משמח בכל עוז בשמחה של מצוה וגם על הגר"א ז"ל כתבו שהיה מרקד לפני הס"ת בכל כחו:      ...  ‏

The  Mishna  Berura mentioned a couple of  responsa from MHRI Kolon advising to maintain all the customs.  He concluded that we must make a special effort to dance for the prestige of Tora,  and reported in name of the   ARI zal this.

Additionally scholars testified that the Ari said about himself that his reached high degree the great gain from Simcha of  Mitsva,  and  that the GRA was dancing with all his strength before t Sefer Tora.

Sitting may be a problem when people pass near you with the  ST. Stand up may be obligatory. Solutions exist to permit sitting.

> `Can someone sit during his Shul's hakofos`

No,  see [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/76858/9215)  link for few explanations.

> `is there an actual obligation to walk around the bimah?`

Not an obligation but a strong advice.

> `Does one have to hold the sefer torah?`

Not mentioned in SA Baer Heytev and MB. But there is mention of multiplying  Aliot (RMA).  (In many  synagogues every body receive an Alya,  but RMA did not say "everybody").

> `Does one have to say the pesukim in the Siddur that introduce each hakafah?`

Not mentioned. Obviously it is impossible to call this an obligation. But maybe a problem to be "batel" when others are saying them. So if you are learning Tora no problem.

Comment: `and reported that ARI zal emphasized the importance of this custom for himself` That's not what your quote says! Your quote just says והעידו על האר"י ז"ל שאמר שהמעלה העליונה שהשיג באה לו ע"י שהיה משמח בכל עוז בשמחה של מצוה that he attained spiritual heights through joyously serving God; nothing at all about Shemini Atseret celebrations.

Comment: @mevaqesh The Ari is mentioned in the first Hebrew quote too וכ"כ משם האר"י

Comment: The 'for himself' quote indicated, I assume that he did do himself, although it's hard to tell exactly what is intended. If so, I don't think the text supports the claim. Even the previous line is ambiguous about which element is supported by the arizal. @DoubleAA